# PHP - не работают cURL и file_get_contents

Tags: php, linux, curl

При попытке получить содержимое страницы через cURL или file_get_contents сервер наглухо виснет, и через секунд 20-30 выдает пустую страницу или вываливается в 504 ошибку. Пробовал разные страницы - тот же результат. При этом на локалке и на другом VDS со схожей конфигурацией PHP все спокойно работает. В чем может быть дело?

p.s.При этом еще и крайне медленно коннектится SSH и FTP (15-20 секунд), несмотря на то, что сам сайт, который хостится на этом сервере, грузится сразу

Comment: При этом еще и крайне медленно коннектится SSH и FTP (15-20 секунд), несмотря на то, что сам сайт, который хостится на этом сервере, грузится сразу.

Comment: Вам быстрее помогут если выложите логи сервера

Comment: Проблема в  том, что в AccessLog есть только это: [06/Oct/2016:12:22:49 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.0" 200.

В ErrorLog по этому поводу пусто.

Comment: если у вас падает php в нём должен быть и error_log, попробуйте протестировать состояние сети на сервере, допустим запустить ping или curl или wget

Comment: Догадка: У провайдера сделана зашита от ботов. Если в  добавите cURL правильные хедеры то будет работать. Такие вопросы надо писать в поддержку провайдеру!